# How to convert querystring to paths URL using mod_rewrite?

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo, query-string

I'm trying to rewrite a URL that has a query string to its SEO friendly name i.e. consider

```
mysite.com/models?p1=v1
```

I'd like to rewrite it to

```
mysite.com/models/p1/v1
```

The user should see the above address in address bar. Any suggesstions?

Comment: Do you want to rewrite any query string into the directory like expression? What should be done with the result to not end in 404 error handler?

Comment: I think you want to the opposite, rewrite `mysite.com/models/p1/v1` to `mysite.com/models?p1=v1` in order that SE-s see `mysite.com/models/p1/v1`

Answer (score 3):

The `.htaccess` should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^models/(.+)/(.+)$ models.php?$1=$2 [NC,L]
```